# Insert my directory image by clicking on an "option"

Tags: php, html, html-select

I am wanting to insert an image into `<img>` by clicking on one of the `<option>` elements, for example, I have a directory with multiple images, and I want to pull a specific image according to the `<option>` ID.

When i click on one of the combobox options i need to insert the image into the `<img>` element

Here is the code

```
<select>                        
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){                            
        print('<option id="img'.$i.'">image'.$i.'</option>');
    }
?>                      
</select>

<img src="#"></img>
```

As you can see, I am loading 10 elements into , but I want to click on one of the elements to open the image according to the name in my directory.

The name of the image in my directory follows this pattern of "img" plus the number in front.

How can I do this?

Comment: you need to use javascript to `listen` for `change` events on the `select` element. The javascript function will help display the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this

```
<select> 
  <option value="">Please select</option>                       
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){ ?>                           
  <option value="img<?= $i ?>">image<?= $i ?></option>
 <?php } ?>                      
</select>
<img src="" id="img1"/>
<script>
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change",function() { 
  var val = this.value;
  if (val) document.getElementById("img1").src=val+".jpg";
})
</script>
```

However if you really know your images are all there, then you can just set the value of the largest number and loop on the client instead

Comment: Is giving this error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: I am not a PHP person. Perhaps `<? } ?>` needs to be `<?php } ?>`